# How to custom format a number in java?

Tags: java, format, number-formatting

I have a string entered by user `25|35|40`. I have format any number below `100=25+35+40` to this format. For instance,

```
5  --> 05|00|00
30 --> 25|05|00
65 --> 25|35|05
```

The order of 25|35|40 should be maintained. This is similar to date formatting MM:dd:yyyy, in that we know month cannot exceed 12 and date cannot exceed 31. but here any value can occur. the value in its position determine the maximum value. Another example,

If the user string is `40|110|2500|350`

```
5    --> 05|000|0000|000
100  --> 40|060|0000|000
450  --> 40|110|0300|000
2900 --> 40|110|2500|250
```

If the number exceeds the total `3000=40+110+2500+350`, I can make it as `number -= 3000`.
Currently I am trying to format it using custom code which will check for the number and will create the required output string. Is there any inbuilt format API available in java?

Comment: Could you explain your formatting a bit better? Should perhaps the last line riead `35|25|05`?

Comment: Seems to be a really specific business case... Can't see any API for that as % and - and string concatenation will be enough to do the job. Why do you format it like that, maybe it will help us to find a tool.

Comment: Could you please expand on how you get from 30/65 to the three numbers?

Comment: BTW, you can create your own `NumberFormat` to encapsulate your business in this API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no public API for such a specific use case. This is one way to solve it:

```
int num = 65;
int i1 = num > 25 ? 25 : num;
int i2 = num < 25 ? 0 : num > 60 ? 35 : num - 25;
int i3 = num < 60 ? 0 : num - 60;
System.out.format("%02d|%02d|%02d", i1, i2, i3);
```

prints

```
25|35|05
```

Or, to generalise it:

```
public static String format(String format, int num) {
    String[] split = format.split("\\|");
    int numLeft = num;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        int boundary = Integer.parseInt(split[i]);
        int number = Math.min(numLeft, boundary);
        if (result.length() > 0) {
            result.append('|');
        }
        result.append(leftPad(number, split[i].length()));
        numLeft = Math.max(0, numLeft - boundary);
    }
    return result.toString();
}

private static String leftPad(int number, int length) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(number);
    while (sb.length() < length) {
        sb.insert(0, '0');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String result = format("25|35|40", 65);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But this is limited to three segments and two decimal formatting only.

Comment: @Ahamed: Yes, didn't see the updated requirements. Now it works for any format you specified.

Comment: What if a segment has more that two digit? :(

Comment: I have taken your previous answer. Just modified `2` in `%02d` with respect to the segment length. Thanks for you time!!!